# Expo SDK 48 app - errors after doing npm install

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an Expo app that just migrated to SDK 48.

I have the following setup:

```
NodeJS: 18.15.0
NPM: 9.6.3
```

When I do: `npm install` I get the following errors:

```
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @koale/useworker@4.0.2
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   30 more (@react-native-firebase/app, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.8.0" from @koale/useworker@4.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/@koale/useworker
npm WARN   @koale/useworker@"^4.0.2" from expo-camera@13.2.1
npm WARN   node_modules/expo-camera
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^16.8.0" from @koale/useworker@4.0.2
npm WARN   node_modules/@koale/useworker
npm WARN     @koale/useworker@"^4.0.2" from expo-camera@13.2.1
npm WARN     node_modules/expo-camera
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-test-renderer@17.0.2
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from @react-native-firebase/app@17.4.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app
npm ERR!     @react-native-firebase/app@"^17.4.2" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @react-native-firebase/app@"17.4.2" from @react-native-firebase/analytics@17.4.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@react-native-firebase/analytics
npm ERR!       @react-native-firebase/analytics@"17.4.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   29 more (@react-native-picker/picker, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"17.0.2" from react-test-renderer@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-test-renderer
npm ERR!   dev react-test-renderer@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react-test-renderer@">=16.8.0" from @testing-library/react-native@12.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react-native
npm ERR!     @testing-library/react-native@"^12.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"17.0.2" from react-test-renderer@17.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-test-renderer
npm ERR!     dev react-test-renderer@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer react-test-renderer@">=16.8.0" from @testing-library/react-native@12.0.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/@testing-library/react-native
npm ERR!       @testing-library/react-native@"^12.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I pray for help!! Please!

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "migrated-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watchAll",
    "types:check": "tsc --noEmit"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@expo/config-plugins": "^5.0."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/inter": "^0.2.2",
    "@expo-google-fonts/open-sans": "^0.2.2",
    "@expo-google-fonts/roboto": "^0.2.2",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.7",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "17.4.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.4.2",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.8",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.5",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.4.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.1.0",
    "@sentry/react-native": "4.13.0",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^12.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^2.3.0",
    "expo": "^48.0.0",
    "expo-ads-admob": "~13.0.0",
    "expo-apple-authentication": "~6.0.1",
    "expo-application": "~5.1.1",
    "expo-asset": "~8.9.1",
    "expo-build-properties": "^0.6.0",
    "expo-camera": "^13.2.1",
    "expo-constants": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-crypto": "~12.2.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.2.1",
    "expo-device": "~5.2.1",
    "expo-facebook": "~12.2.0",
    "expo-firebase-analytics": "^8.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-in-app-purchases": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-linking": "~4.0.1",
    "expo-location": "~15.1.1",
    "expo-mail-composer": "~12.1.1",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.18.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "expo-updates": "~0.16.4",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.1.1",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jest-circus": "^29.1.2",
    "jotai": "^1.6.6",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.32.1",
    "react-native": "0.71.6",
    "react-native-autocomplete-input": "^5.1.0",
    "react-native-bouncy-checkbox": "^2.1.10",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-global-props": "^1.1.5",
    "react-native-maps": "1.3.2",
    "react-native-purchases": "^5.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "react-native-webview": "11.26.0",
    "react-query": "^3.39.1",
    "sentry-expo": "~6.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.24",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.70.6",
    "@types/react-native-autocomplete-input": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/react-native-global-props": "^1.1.1",
    "detox": "^19.12.5",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "lint-staged": "^12.4.1",
    "prettier": "2.6.2",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  },
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "npm": ">=7.0.0",
    "node": "18.15.0"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{jsx,tsx,ts,js,css,md}": "prettier --write",
    "*.{js,css,md}": "prettier --write"
  },
  "detox": {
    "test-runner": "jest",
    "configurations": {
      "ios.sim": {
        "binaryPath": "bin/Exponent.app",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "name": "iPhone 11"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: After a very quick search on the Expo issues list ~ https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/17846. I'm surprised you didn't check there first

Comment: I checked that and didnt fix the issues @Phil

Answer (score 0):

I found how to solve the issue.

1. First I change to NodeJS 16.15.0
2. Then, upgrade the version of react-test-renderer to 18.2.0

That solved all the issues with npm install